# Microsoft Teams - multiselect in ms teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How to implement multiselect in drop down list through adaptive cards to fill a form which contains the name of employees to select.

If not what are the other ways to implement multiselect in Ms Teams through bot.

Multiselect like [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.syncfusion.com%2Fvisual-studio-market%2Fej2%2Fjavascript%2Fshowcase%2Fmultiselect-dropdown.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fitems%3FitemName%3DSyncfusionInc.javascript-multiselect-dropdown&tbnid=_2c6hOD7kvS27M&vet=12ahUKEwjI1ejc_7DqAhVEQn0KHR8DD38QMygUegUIARDwAQ..i&docid=1wGG1wJMtmHk-M&w=1320&h=686&q=multiselect%20dropdown&ved=2ahUKEwjI1ejc_7DqAhVEQn0KHR8DD38QMygUegUIARDwAQ).

Answer (score 1):

Check and build [samples](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/CalendarReminder.html).
Check this sample Adaptive card

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"speak": "<s>Your  meeting about \"Adaptive Card design session\"<break strength='weak'/> is starting at ${formatDateTime(start.dateTime, 'HH:mm')}pm</s><s>Do you want to snooze <break strength='weak'/> or do you want to send a late notification to the attendees?</s>",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "${summary}",
        "size": "Large",
        "weight": "Bolder"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": " ${location} ",
        "isSubtle": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "${formatDateTime(start.dateTime, 'HH:mm')} - ${formatDateTime(end.dateTime, 'hh:mm')}",
        "isSubtle": true,
        "spacing": "None"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Snooze for"
    },
    {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "id": "snooze",
        "value": "${reminders.overrides[0].minutes}",
        "choices": [
                 {
                "$data": "${reminders.overrides}",
                "title": "${hours} hours",
                "value": "${hours}"
            },
            {
                "$data": "${reminders.overrides}",
                "title": "${minutes} minutes",
                "value": "${minutes}"
            },
                 {
                "$data": "${reminders.overrides}",
                "title": "${seconds} seconds",
                "value": "${seconds}"
            }

        ],
        "isMultiSelect": true
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Snooze",
        "data": {
            "x": "snooze"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "I'll be late",
        "data": {
            "x": "late"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: In designer this will show checkbox, when you send card in teams - it will show dropdown list.

Comment: Its showing dropdown list in desktop app but not in android app. Can you please check that in android app. Thanks

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have a dropdown where choosing an option results in a Submit action?

Comment: @konrad - You can use input.choiceset to show as a drop?id that does not work for you?

Comment: I'd like a dropdown where the user does not have to press another button to confirm the selection, e.g. selecting an item triggers a Submit action @Nikitha-MSFT