# Chatbot with multiselect option (for Microsoft Teams)

Tags: botframework, chatbot

Is there an official sample on how to do it with version 4 of the SDK?
I have just started with chatbots.

Comment: HI, this question is already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715198/microsoft-teams-multiselect-in-ms-teams-bot